# How to pick apart array data

Tags: python, mongodb, bottle

Trying to output just the employee data(empfirst, emplast, empsalary, emproles) to a bottle project. I Just want the value not the keys. How would I go about this? It feels like i've tried everything but can't get at the data I need!

My query

````
    emp_curs = connection.coll.find({},{"_id": False,"employee.empFirst":True})
    dept_list = list(emp_curs)```

(just playing with the first name for now until its working)

My loop
    ```% for d in emp_list:
        % for i in d:
                <tr>
                    <td>{{d[i]}}</td>
                    <td>{{d[i]}}</td>
                    <td>{{d[i]}}</td>
                    <td>{{d[i]}}</td>
                </tr>
        %end
    %end```

thats the closest i've gotten :\
Looking to take all the data and place in a table.

Sorry, here is the whole data file!
Sorry, here's some sample data

[
    {
      "deptCode": "ACCT",
      "deptName": "Accounting",
      "deptBudget": 200000,
      "employee": [
        {
          "empFirst": "Marsha",
          "empLast": "Bonavoochi",
          "empSalary": 59000
        },
        {
          "empFirst": "Roberto",
          "empLast": "Acostaletti",
          "empSalary": 85000,
          "empRoles": [
            "Manager"
          ]
        },
        {
          "empFirst": "Dini",
          "empLast": "Cappelletti",
          "empSalary": 50500
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
````

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are stopping just one layer early within your nested list of dictionaries. This should get you all the applicable values for the employee data:

```
for department in department_list:
    for employee in department["employee"]:
        for value in employee.values():
            print(value) # or whatever operation you want, adding to the table in your case
```

Looks like you have adding to the table working as you want, so that should work for you. Based on the structure of your sample data, I'm assuming there will be multiple departments to pull this data from (hence me starting with `department_list`).

Comment: Coming back with this error:  AttributeError("'str' object has no attribute 'values'",)

Comment: In your case is `emp_list` the equivalent of the data you provided? Update: oops, I forgot to specify `department["employee"]` in line two. Give it a try now.

Comment: any idea how I could nicely order in a table? the output seems a little wonky right now. Here is what I did on my other page and it worked well: 
`code`% for d in dept_list:
 %format_budget = '${:,.2f}'.format(d["deptBudget"])
  <tr>
   <td>{{d["deptCode"]}}</td>
   <td>{{d["deptName"]}}</td>
   <td>{{format_budget}}</td>
  </tr>
 % end`code`

Comment: I don't have experience with that because I don't really do web development but I think these two resources could help: [a library](https://www.decalage.info/python/html) and [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064938/python-html-for-loop-format). Hope that's helpful!